# The relation between the derivative and the nondecreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-forms

İ want just a simple explaining about the derivatives with the nondecreasing functions : 
İf we have a nondecreasing function f and :

$
{f}\prime{(}{t}_{1}{)}\leq{f}\prime{(}{t}_{2}{)}
$
Does it lead to :

$
{t}_{1}\mathrm{\leq}{t}_{2}
$
 İs the converse true ?? 
İ know that if the function nondecreasing and we have :

$
{t}_{1}\mathrm{\leq}{t}_{2}
$
Then we

$
{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{1}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{2}{\mathrm{)}}
$
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the first statement with $f(x)=x$, it is nondecreasing and $f'(x)=1$. For the converse try $log(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=x^3$. Then, $f'(x)=3x^2$ and we have $f'(0)\leq f'(-1)$ as $0\leq 3$. This shows that both implications do not hold.